# HTTP Post works with WIFI But not Cell

Tags: ios, swift, http, nsurl

I asked a previous question earlier. It worked for a day, then it now doesn't work. Something seems to have happened.

When I send an HTTP post request from my actual device to my server using WIFI, the message is sent. However, when using the cellular service, something is going on. No message is being sent. The weird part is I requested cellular access and it worked earlier.

I changed my developer profile. Do I need to update my profile with something special? This new developer profile doesn't have any certs (it's the free kind). The old one may have (it wansn't mine...) . I did notice my background processes stopped working as well. Is this because of my developing profile as well?

Here is the code in question. Is it my code's fault or my provisioning profile fault? What should I do? =(

```
if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted) {

        let url = NSURL(string: base_address + location_address)!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.allowsCellularAccess=true
        request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
            if error != nil{
                self.statusLabel.text = error?.localizedDescription
                return
            }

            do {

                self.statusLabel.text = "success"
            } catch let error as NSError {
                self.statusLabel.text = error.localizedDescription
                print(error)
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: are you sure its not a setting on your phone, if you go data > is the toggle next to your app in settings 'allowing data'

Comment: That's a brilliant point. When I go to cellular -> use cellular data for ... , my app isn't listed with a toggle...Is this because it wasn't listed through the app store? I installed it via xcode, by clicking run on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I was using a computer with a firewall that allowed same network traffic. But, cell data is on a different network (i.e. 3G 4G)